# Please help me read this board

Tags: readings, writing-identification

So I tried to read what's written on this board in a manga, but a portion of it is too blurry for me to try to seach the kanji in a dictionnary.

It would be great if someone was able to recognize the words and help me read them.

Here's the image :

[image]

I got

> xxx を入れて
>
> お待ちしてます。
>
> 二x
>
> 佐x眼鏡堂

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this...

> **珈琲** を入れて
>
> お待ちしてます。
>
> 二 **階**
>
> 佐 **藤** 眼鏡堂